# TabHost looses view on intent

Tags: android, android-intent, view, android-tabhost

I have two tabs for two activities in my TabHost(MainActivityTabs).My problem is when i try to open the second activity from the first one using intents , the TabHost looses its view ,meaning a can't see the two tabs on the bottom and the second activity is on the full screen.

~The main activity ~

```
public class MainActivityTabs extends TabActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tabs);

    Resources ressources = getResources();

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, First.class);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("First")
            .setIndicator("",
                    ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.search))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Second.class);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Second")
            .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.favorites))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}
```

}

```
~first class ~


    public class First extends Activity{
      @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first);
   Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Second.class);

    int i =1;
    intent.putExtra("somthing", i);
    startActivity(intent);
     }


 }
```

~Second class~

```
      public class First extends Activity{
    @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sec);

     }


  }
```

Comment: The TabActivity has been **deprecated** for years and you **SHOULDN'T** be using it at all. Also, why are you extending the ActivityGroup instead of activity?

Comment: and what should i use instead of tabActivity?

Comment: Use fragments instead of TabActivity.

Comment: and2 buttons for the 2 tabs i guess to start the fragments

Comment: TabActivity is deprecated, TabHost isn't. You also have FragmentTabHost specially designed for fragments.